# All BiBTeX keys give the same citation

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib

I am currently working on a presentation that includes citations and at some point LaTeX (or rather BiBTeX) linked all BibTeX keys to the same reference, so now it looks like this:

[image]

Obviously, only one of those references should be to Carvalho et al. 2010, all others have other bibtex entries with unique and distinct bibtex keys. In fact, this behaviour is curiously created now even when I re-compile some old presentations that compiled fine even just a week ago. Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[t,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
%% PACKAGES
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array,multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bbm}

%\usetheme[style=free]{wu}

\title[Title]{\textbf{Title}\\ Subtitle}
\author[Author]{Mr Author}
\date{June 26, 2020}
\institute[]{University}

\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}

    \section{Statistical model and shrinkage estimation}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Shrinkage methods}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Many options for shrinkage priors: Bayesian Lasso \citep{Park2008}, spike-and-slab (two-component discrete mixture prior by \cite{Mitchell1988} and \cite{George1993}), Normal-Gamma prior \citep{Griffin2010}, Horseshoe \citep{Carvalho2010}, \cite{Piironen2017}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
            
    \beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<.->}
    \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
        \frametitle{References}
        \scriptsize
        \bibliographystyle{apa}
        \bibliography{BE_I_Bib}
        \normalsize
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The corresponding .bib file (BE_I_Bib.bib) looks as follows:

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@Article{Park2008,
  author       = {Trevor Park and George Casella},
  journal      = {Journal of the American Statistical Association},
  title        = {The Bayesian Lasso},
  year         = {2008},
  number       = {482},
  pages        = {681-686},
  volume       = {103},
  date         = {2008},
  journaltitle = {Journal of the American Statistical Association},
}

@Article{George1993,
  author  = {George, E. I. and McCulloch, R.E.},
  journal = {Journal of the American Statistical Association},
  title   = {Variable selection via Gibbs sampling},
  year    = {1993},
  number  = {423},
  pages   = {881-889},
  volume  = {88},
}

@Article{Mitchell1988,
  author    = {T. J. Mitchell and J. J. Beauchamp},
  journal   = {Journal of the American Statistical Association},
  title     = {Bayesian Variable Selection in Linear Regression},
  year      = {1988},
  issn      = {01621459},
  number    = {404},
  pages     = {1023--1032},
  volume    = {83},
  publisher = {[American Statistical Association, Taylor & Francis, Ltd.]},
  url       = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/2290129},
}

@Article{Griffin2010,
  author    = {Griffin, Jim E. and Brown, Philip J.},
  journal   = {Bayesian Anal.},
  title     = {Inference with normal-gamma prior distributions in regression problems},
  year      = {2010},
  month     = {03},
  number    = {1},
  pages     = {171--188},
  volume    = {5},
  doi       = {10.1214/10-BA507},
  fjournal  = {Bayesian Analysis},
  publisher = {International Society for Bayesian Analysis},
  url       = {https://doi.org/10.1214/10-BA507},
}

@Article{Carvalho2010,
  author    = {Carlos M. Carvalho and Nicholas G. Polson and James G. Scott},
  journal   = {Biometrika},
  title     = {The horseshoe estimator for sparse signals},
  year      = {2010},
  issn      = {00063444},
  number    = {2},
  pages     = {465--480},
  volume    = {97},
  url       = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/25734098},
}

@Article{Piironen2017,
  author    = {Piironen, Juho and Vehtari, Aki},
  journal   = {Electron. J. Statist.},
  title     = {Sparsity information and regularization in the horseshoe and other shrinkage priors},
  year      = {2017},
  number    = {2},
  pages     = {5018--5051},
  volume    = {11},
  doi       = {10.1214/17-EJS1337SI},
  fjournal  = {Electronic Journal of Statistics},
  publisher = {The Institute of Mathematical Statistics and the Bernoulli Society},
  url       = {https://doi.org/10.1214/17-EJS1337SI},
}

@Comment{jabref-meta: databaseType:bibtex;}
```

I tried everything straightforward: set up a new presentation and new bibtex file, updated all packages, compiled in different softwares (TeXStudio and TeXworks) and even different OS (Windows and Linux), but nothing worked, as soon as there were at least two references, all citations were associated with the same reference regardless of the used Bibtex key. I only found a manual way of solving this which is to change the following section in the .aux file:

```
\bibstyle{apa}
\bibdata{BE_I_Bib}
\bibcite{Carvalho2010}{{1}{2010}{{Carvalho et~al.}}{{}}}
\bibcite{George1993}{{2}{2010}{{Carvalho et~al.}}{{}}}
\bibcite{Griffin2010}{{3}{2010}{{Carvalho et~al.}}{{}}}
\bibcite{Mitchell1988}{{4}{2010}{{Carvalho et~al.}}{{}}}
\bibcite{Park2008}{{5}{2010}{{Carvalho et~al.}}{{}}}
\bibcite{Piironen2017}{{6}{2010}{{Carvalho et~al.}}{{}}}
```

This is obviously where the problem comes from, but I have no idea why. I manually replaced the incorrectly assigned "Carvalho et~al." there with the corresponding correct author names for each bibtex key. This then works for one compilation, but as soon as I change something, everything is incorrectly assigned again and I have to start from the beginning.
Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: That's a cool issue! (I mean: Obviously not a cool issue to have, but a really interesting problem.) The problem appears to go away when I remove the two `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification` calls, but I have no idea why...

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  You're using `beamer`; don't remember seeing any bibliography problems reported recently with that combination.  The other thing that  I don't remember seeing is a "bare" `apa`; what shows up around here is usually `apa6` or `apa7`.  You might check to see if either of those has changed recently.

Comment: Possibly better solution: Replace the `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<.->}` before the bibliography with `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{}`. According to the `beamer` docs `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{}` is the correct way to reset the overlay specification.

Comment: @barbarabeeton [`apa.bst`](https://ctan.org/pkg/apabst) is from 1992 and probably not a style anyone would want to use in a new document. But the problem persists with a "standard style" like `plainnat.bst`.

Comment: The `beamer` docs also say "You will only have to use this command if you wish to do
funny things." about `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification`, so maybe you don't actually need the `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}` or could replace it with less destructive code? (What do you need `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification` for?)

Comment: @moewe -- You obviously know more what you're talking about than I do.  Thanks for the history.  (My first reaction was to suggest adding `beamer` as a tag.  Should have, I guess.)

Comment: Thank you both for your very helpful comments! Indeed using \beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{} to reset the overlay specification helped and now it works. Must have been some change in a package because just over a week ago the procedure worked fine in other presentations of mine... Thank you again!